# Bookshelf.js: Cascade save?

Tags: bookshelf.js

Does Bookshelf support cascading related entities on save?

I see that we can [declare associations on the model](http://bookshelfjs.org/#associations).

However, for instance, when I have a `Book`

```
var Book = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'books',
   pages: function() {
      return this.hasMany(Page);
   }
});
```

Which has a non-null `pages` field, and I save a Book, it tries to store the pages array as a single JSON LOB object into the DB, rather than performing a cascade save on `Pages`'s table.

The documentation doesn't mention anything about cascading.

**Can we do cascade on save with Bookshelf and if so, how?**

Comment: A similar question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715684/bookshelf-js-how-to-save-many-to-many-relationship